# Custom dynamic sized wpf button with animation

Tags: wpf, animation, dynamic, wpf-style

I am trying to learn how to do wpf styling using control templates by making a custom toggle button for fun and profit and now some headaches too. My idea is to make a simple toggle button which when clicked will animate a little triangle down from the top. I should add that I am reasonably new to wpf and I don't know all the neat tricks you can do with wpf, so if my way of doing this is completely wrong then I am open to anything that can help and improve my understanding of wpf.

This is kind of a 3 part question, so here it goes:

no.1 One problem I am having is that I can't figure out how to fire an animation when the checked value gets changed, and then to be able to decide which animation to show depending on the state of the checked value. What I have now just changes to opacity.

no.2 The other problem that I tend to face in general with translation animations is that when a control can be resized and you want to move the control by using the margin property, you can get bad results from the animation. In this case the 3rd button barely moves the triangle down when it should be coming from above the button. Is there a way to bind the one side of the margin to be the height of the control minus 10? so that is will always appear slightly offscreen before the animation

no.3 If you've run the code you will have noticed that the triangle animates down but is still visible outside of the actual button. I don't know how to make it so that the Triangle will only be visible from inside the buttons Border.

Front end xaml on a Window

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Base_SwapIconButton"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel Width="100" Height="200">
            <TextBlock Text="small" TextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Border Margin="0,10,0,0" Width="100" Height="160">
                <ToggleButton Width="40" Height="40" Template="{StaticResource Base_SwapIconButton}"/>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Width="100" Height="200">
            <TextBlock Text="medium" TextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Border Margin="0,10,0,0" Width="100" Height="160">
                <ToggleButton Width="80" Height="80" Template="{StaticResource Base_SwapIconButton}"/>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Width="200" Height="200">
            <TextBlock Text="large" TextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Border Margin="0,10,0,0" Width="160" Height="160">
                <ToggleButton Width="160" Height="160" Template="{StaticResource Base_SwapIconButton}" Content="button" />
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Resource template

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="Base_SwapIconButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">

    <!--background and icon-->
    <Border x:Name="back" Background="#969696" CornerRadius="10">
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse x:Name="icon" Margin="8" Fill="#97FFFF"/>
            <Polygon x:Name="iconTri" Points="0,0 3,0 1.5,2.5" Stroke="Red" Fill="Red" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="5,10,5,5"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

    <!--Triggers-->
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="icon" Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
            <Setter TargetName="iconTri" Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="icon" Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
            <Setter TargetName="iconTri" Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
        </Trigger>

        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="back" Duration="0:0:.1"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="#46328C"  />
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="back" BeginTime="0:0:.1" Duration="0:0:.4" 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="#646464"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I hope this is not too long and at least makes sense, any and all help is welcome. Thanks!